# Query to split time segment into smaller segments

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I Have the following given:

1- Employee schedule

```
declare @table table (EmployeeId int,StartOn datetime,EndOn datetime)
insert into @table(EmployeeId,StartOn,EndOn)
values(1,'15 Dec 2015 09:00','15 Dec 2015 17:00')
```

2- Break time taken

```
declare @break table(EmployeeId int,StartOn datetime,EndOn datetime)
insert into @break(EmployeeId,StartOn,EndOn)
values(1,'15 Dec 2015 09:45','15 Dec 2015 10:10')
insert into @break(EmployeeId,StartOn,EndOn)
values(1,'15 Dec 2015 11:30','15 Dec 2015 12:00')
```

3 - the out come should come as

```
EmployeeId  Date          From      To     Type
1          '15 Dec 2015'  '09:00'  '09:45'  'F' -- Working
1          '15 Dec 2015'  '09:45'  '09:10'  'B' -- Break
1          '15 Dec 2015'  '10:10'  '11:30'  'F' -- Working
1          '15 Dec 2015'  '11:30'  '12:00'  'B' -- Break
1          '15 Dec 2015'  '12:00'  '17:00'  'F' -- Working
```

currently i am able to get this result as cursor, i would like to increase the performance and convert this outcome from cursor to query.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Alas, I think the solution either requires cumulative sums, `lag()`, or recursive CTEs.  In SQL Server 2008, none of these might be much faster than a cursor-based solution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i edited the tags, i would like to see how this can be done using lag or recursive cte, now i am trying to solve it using recursive actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
;WITH BreaksPlusEndOfDay AS (
    SELECT * FROM @break 
    UNION 
    SELECT EmployeeId, EndOn, NULL FROM @table --Needed to get the final "F"
), BreakInfo AS (
    --Find the previous break end for each break (+ end of day) so that we have all the
    --info to generate both the break record and the previous working record
    SELECT CurrentBreak.EmployeeId, CurrentBreak.StartOn, CurrentBreak.EndOn, 
        (SELECT MAX(PreviousBreaks.EndOn) AS PreviousBreak_EndOn
        FROM @break PreviousBreaks
        WHERE CurrentBreak.EmployeeId = PreviousBreaks.EmployeeId 
        AND CAST(CurrentBreak.StartOn as date) = CAST(PreviousBreaks.StartOn as date)
        AND CurrentBreak.StartOn > PreviousBreaks.StartOn
        ) AS PreviousBreak_EndOn
    FROM BreaksPlusEndOfDay CurrentBreak
),
WorkOrBreak AS (SELECT 'F' AS FB UNION SELECT 'B' AS FB) --Virtual table with 2 recs
SELECT BreakInfo.EmployeeId, 
    CAST(BreakInfo.StartOn as date), 
    CAST(CASE WHEN FB = 'F' THEN ISNULL(PreviousBreak_EndOn, T.StartOn) ELSE BreakInfo.StartOn END AS time) AS StartOn, 
    CAST(CASE WHEN FB = 'F' THEN BreakInfo.StartOn ELSE BreakInfo.EndOn END AS time) AS EndOn, 
    FB
FROM BreakInfo 
JOIN @table AS T ON BreakInfo.EmployeeId = T.EmployeeID AND CAST(BreakInfo.StartOn AS date) = CAST(T.StartOn AS date)
CROSS JOIN WorkOrBreak --Generate 2 recs for each rec in BreakInfo
WHERE FB = 'F' OR BreakInfo.EndOn IS NOT NULL --Remove the "end of day" break
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

You should test it thoroughly though, also performance. I have no idea if this will actually be faster than your cursor.

Comment: Just noticed I forgot to delete the GROUP BY CurrentBreak.StartOn, CurrentBreak.EndOn, CurrentBreak.EmployeeId from a previous attempt, will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As recommended by Gordon Linoff

here what i got

```
;with counting as (
    select EmployeeId,count(*) as Number
    from @break
    group by EmployeeId
), combine as (
    select t.EmployeeId,t.StartOn,t.EndOn,b.StartOn as TimeStart,b.EndOn as TimeEnd,c.Number, lead(b.StartOn,1,t.EndOn) over(order by b.StartOn) as Next
        , lag(b.EndOn,1,t.StartOn) over(order by b.StartOn) as Previous,Duration
    from @table t
    inner join @break b on b.EmployeeId = t.EmployeeId
    inner join counting c on c.EmployeeId=b.EmployeeId
), sorting as(
    select EmployeeId,TimeStart,TimeEnd,Duration,Number,Next,Previous,row_number() over(order by TimeStart) as [Row]
    from combine
), query as(
    select EmployeeId,
         TimeStart as StartOn, 
         TimeEnd as EndOn, 'A' as Type,Duration
    from sorting
    union all
    select EmployeeId,
         Previous,
         TimeStart, 'F' as Type,Duration
    from sorting
    union all 
    select EmployeeId,
         TimeEnd,
         [Next], 'F' as Type,Duration
    from sorting
    where [Row]=Number
)
select * from query order by StartOn
```

hope it will help other developers

Comment: what will be the result if there is no records in @break table? i think it needs some improvements